# Sending data to a Docusign Powerform through POST creates two envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I am directing my customers to Docusign through a POST form on my website to generate the data to populate the fields on the PDF to sign. The code looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=$powerFormId" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Signer_UserName" id="Signer_UserName" value="John Smith">
    <input type="hidden" name="Signer_Email" id="Signer_Email" value="hello@mail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="dsCustomerId" id="dsCustomerId" value="1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="dsCompany" id="dsCompany" value="Hello Inc.">
    <input class="form_submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

'dsCustomerId' and 'dsCompany' are the names of the fields on my PDF that I want to populate. The tag labels are set accordingly.

Until a couple weeks ago, this was working fine. The customer ID and company name were populated in the correct fields on the PDF. Now it doesn't anymore, nothing is populated.

I've found in my Docusign account that, for each time this form was submitted, two envelopes were created. The first one is correct, with the data populated as it should, the second one has no data. And we are shown the latter when coming from our form. I know that the first one works because we can access it by manually sending it back by email in the Docusign account.

When accessing the PowerForm url in GET, it works fine. Only one envelope is created with the data populated as it should be when adding it as additional parameters in the URL. But I have a lot of data to pass through so I can't go with that.

I know that I only send the form once (no double-click on the button).

Docusign support says that they haven't change anything lately and that there must be something in my code that gets the thing to crash. But I cannot see what could be wrong in my very simple form to trigger that behaviour.

Has anyone encountered this problem so far? And if so, what solution did you come up with to solve it?

Comment: If you use the PowreForm directly, by going to the URL and trying to fill it from there, does it work ok then? only one envelope created?

Comment: Yes, in GET it works fine. I only get one envelope, with the fields working properly.

Comment: ok, that proves it has to do with your code. I wonder what is the purpose of this code? there are ways to show parameters on the standard PowerForm page, is that not working or good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs can be quite long (8,000 characters or more). Why not continue with a GET instead of a POST?

Older browsers have had problems with longer URLs in the past, but that's for displaying the URL in the browser. In this case, the long URL is only be used in the GET `request` to the server.

I would also use Fiddler or WireShark to see exactly what you're sending to DocuSign.

Comment: Well I didn't want to but I went with GET eventually. It works but I'm genuinely curious as to why it stopped working in POST. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thank you for the check! I would also like to know what happened with the POST. You could also try DocuSign's API logging with the POST to see what's happening.

Comment: Just adding a note here. GET requests are case sensitive in docusign, so signer_UserName will not fill data if the role is named Signer, use Signer_UserName instead.